# removing 'categories' title from list

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following code which creates a list with all my categories and an 'all posts'. However it also outputs a 'category' on top of the list. I would like to remove that, and just have the list items.

HTML

```
<?php
  $args = array(
  'show_option_all' => 'All posts'
  );
?>

<h3><?php wp_list_categories($args); ?></h3>
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: You will need the edit the wp_list_categories function, can you update the post and paste the wp_list_categories function pls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `title_li` argument value to empty string. Refer the [**WordPress Codex**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_or_Hide_the_List_Heading)

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'show_option_all' => 'All posts',
    'title_li' => ''
  );
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''title li'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'